# Meteor - DDPRateLimiter

Tags: meteor

From the [meteor documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/ddpratelimiter):

> By default, DDPRateLimiter is configured with a single rule. This rule
>   limits login attempts, new user creation, and password resets to 5
>   attempts every 10 seconds per connection.

Can't understand this. Should I do something to turn on `DDPRateLimiter` for login attempts, new user creation, and password resets?

Comment: Looks like it's on by default from the quote you have provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 5 attempts every 10 seconds per connection for login attempts, new user creation, and password resets works for you, you don't have to do nothing, as it's the default (*but it's always good to check the docs as Meteor is evolving very fast*).

If want to change these values or even add other methods and/or subscriptions, you do need to add this packet:

```
meteor add ddp-rate-limiter
```

Here is an excerpt from the **todos** example [`meteor create --example todos`] where the server methods are added to a rule to limit its operations per second:

```js
// Get list of all method names on Lists
const LISTS_METHODS = _.pluck([
  insert,
  makePublic,
  makePrivate,
  updateName,
  remove,
], 'name');

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  // Only allow 5 list operations per connection per second
  DDPRateLimiter.addRule({
    name(name) {
      return _.contains(LISTS_METHODS, name);
    },

    // Rate limit per connection ID
    connectionId() { return true; },
  }, 5, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DDP rate limiter define the rules for the methods. You can installed it in your meteor project.

```
meteor add ddp-rate-limiter@1.0.6
```

Add following code in your both or server directory files and define the list of methods

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    DDPRateLimiter.addRule({
        name(name) {
            return _.contains([
                //name of methods
            ], name);
        },
        // Rate limit per connection ID
        connectionId() {
            return true;
        }
    }, 20, 1000);
}
```